# How can I make a char a= ‘+’(or string[]) into a real operation?

Tags: c++

Ex:5 a 5 =  10. I am trying to do a linear equation calculator and I am beginning with an string. I can convert it to numbers but not make the chat equivalent to the + sign ( for example) actually do what a + sign does...

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie my bad

Comment: ok, it depends on how sophisticated your input is.  You need to tell us the level of sophistication of the input string before anyone could give you an answer or suggestion.  Whatever the level is, it isn't automatic -- you have to write the code to interpret the `+` to mean "add up".

Comment: My input is a linear equation of any sort. Ex: 1+x=5*3.

Comment: Linear equation -- I think you've underestimated what needs to be done.  It requires you to build a parser, and after that, actually solve the equation.  This requires a lot more work than simply trying to get '+' to do addition.

Comment: If you are serious about pursuing this project, you will probably need to learn _lex/flex_ and _yacc/bison_.

Comment: And after you've parsed your string, Gaussian elimination or some other method to solve the equation (if you try and do symbolic manipulation to solve the equation, i.e. like we did in junior high school, expect the difficulty level to increase many-fold).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Wow... I had no idea how complicated this is. Thank you for suggesting some subjects I need to study to get there.

Comment: `if(ch == '+') result = a + b; else if(ch == '-') result = a - b; else ...` or the same thing using `switch`.

Comment: @2False If you constrain the user to enter very specific input strings (e.g., no spaces, only one letter variables, no reducible expressions like 5*3 etc.), I think the parsing is a lot less complicated than what others are suggesting and can be a great way to learn basic concepts/difficulties behind compilation. You can simply read the string character by character and convert it to vectors along the way. Then you solve the equation (you'll have to implement a solver). After that, slowly add more freedom to what the user can input. This is not an easy task, but a very interesting one.

Comment: @Gilles-PhilippePaillé -- The one issue with writing a parser in a sort of ad-hoc way for specific strings is that if you need to add features, the parsing code that was previously written needs to be thrown away and started from scratch.   Trying to tweak existing "simple" code to implement  new features is almost like trying to break a padlock with your hands. That's why it's best to learn the formal way of how to parse data (grammar rules, recursive descent, etc.) before embarking in this type of project.

Answer (score 0):

In c-style languages, code is compiled before it can be run, so you can't just directly run a string as if it were code at runtime. However, you could build a rudimentary interpreter do accomplish your task. For example:

```
if (op == '+') {
  result = a + b;
} else if (op == '-') {
  result = a - b;
}
```

Comment: True, but too incomplete to be worth an upvote. How does the asker get `a`, `b`, and `op` into the program? How do they handle more complicated stuff like `1+x=5*3` from the comments? This is way, WAY more difficult than the Into to Programming  "Write a calculator" assignment.

Comment: Hmm ok I thought that OP just was trying to calculate simple a+b, a-b type stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can convert the characters in the string to something that provide more information.

I have wrote an example (very simple) that handle characters from A-Z and a-z as variables, 0-9 as constants, and the standard operators `'+'`, `'-'`, `'*'` and `'/'`.

It handles only integers problems and few operators but it is just a simple example only meant to illustrate my idea.

---

**Code**

*tools.h*

```
#ifndef TOOLS_H
#define TOOLS_H

#include <vector>
#include <string>

namespace interp
{
    enum class ITEM_TYPE {OPERATOR, OPERAND};
    enum class VAR_TYPE {CONSTANT, VARIABLE};
    enum class SOLVE_STATUS{SUCCESS, FAILED};

    const int solve_init_value = 0; // Value used for initializing variables for the solve algorithm

    struct Item
    {
        ITEM_TYPE item_t;
        Item(ITEM_TYPE t);
    };

    struct Operator : public Item
    {
        char op;
        Operator(char o);
        int operate(int a, int b);
    };

    struct Operand : public Item
    {
        VAR_TYPE var_t;
        int value;
        Operand(VAR_TYPE t, int v);
    };

    std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string & s, char c);
    Item * convert(char c);

    SOLVE_STATUS solve(std::vector<Item*> lhs, std::vector<Item*> rhs);
}

#endif // TOOLS_H
```

*tools.cpp*

```
#include "tools.h"

namespace interp
{
    Item::Item(ITEM_TYPE t) : item_t(t)
    {}
    // ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
    Operator::Operator(char o) : Item(ITEM_TYPE::OPERATOR), op(o)
    {}
    int Operator::operate(int a, int b)
    {
        int res;
        switch(op)
        {
            case '+': res = a+b; break;
            case '-': res = a-b; break;
            case '*': res = a*b; break;
            case '/': res = a/b; break;
            default: /* Do what you want */ throw std::string("Unknown Operator");
        }
        return res;
    }
    // ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
    Operand::Operand(VAR_TYPE t, int v) : Item (ITEM_TYPE::OPERAND), var_t(t), value(v)
    {}
    // ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
    std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string & s, char c)
    {
        std::vector<std::string> splitted;

        std::string word;
        for(char ch : s)
        {
            if((ch == c) && (!word.empty()))
            {
                splitted.push_back(word);
                word.clear();
            }
            else
                word += ch;
        }
        if(!word.empty())
            splitted.push_back(word);

        return splitted;
    }
    // ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
    Item * convert(char c)
    {
        if((c < 48) || (c > 126)) // check for invalid characters
            return nullptr;

        if((c >= 48) && (c <= 57)) // constant integer values (0 to 9)
            return new Operand(VAR_TYPE::CONSTANT, static_cast<int>(c));
        if((c >= 65) && (c <= 90)) // variable integer values (char A-Z)
            return new Operand(VAR_TYPE::VARIABLE, solve_init_value);
        if((c >= 97) && (c <= 122)) // variable integer values (char a-z)
            return new Operand(VAR_TYPE::VARIABLE, solve_init_value);

        return new Operator(c);
    }
}
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include "tools.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string equation("1+x=5*3");

    std::vector<std::string> separatedSides(interp::split(equation, '='));
    if(separatedSides.size() != 2)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: Too many '=' found in the string." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    std::vector<interp::Item *> leftHandSide;
    std::vector<interp::Item *> rightHandSide;

    // Convert the left hand side
    for(char c : separatedSides[0])
    {
        interp::Item * item(interp::convert(c));
        if(item != nullptr)
            leftHandSide.push_back(item);
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Error: Unknown character encountered." << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
    }
    // Convert the right hand side
    for(char c : separatedSides[1])
    {
        interp::Item * item(interp::convert(c));
        if(item != nullptr)
            rightHandSide.push_back(interp::convert(c));
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Error: Unknown character encountered." << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
    }

    // Now you can solve the problem knowing what Item is.
    interp::SOLVE_STATUS status = interp::solve(leftHandSide, rightHandSide);

    // Release memory at the end
    for(interp::Item * item : leftHandSide)
        delete item;
    for(interp::Item * item : rightHandSide)
        delete item;
    leftHandSide.clear();
    rightHandSide.clear();

    return 0;
}
```

---

**Explanation**

I didn't write the solve method (just written in the header but not implemented), this is more your job than mine :)

But, with that `Item` formulation of characters, you can easily identify what is what (`Operand` (constant or variable) or `Operator`).

In `Operator` items, you have the method `operate()` that can perform the operation for you, so that in your `solve()` function, you just have to call this function and check that no error happened (for unknown operators for example).

So you can adapt this code to your case, in order to handle more complex cases, for example the `(` and `)` for the priority rules, double values instead of just integers (`.`), ...

Perhaps the code needs some adjustments but this is not my point.

I hope it can help.